# Recipe Ingredient Conversion

Tags: c#, sql

I have a question concerning fractions, decimals, and recipes.

Let's get the obvious out of the way. This is not a homework assignment (I already have two college degrees, I don't need any more). This is for my only personal project.

The situation is this. I have a recipe database. It is already being used in a program that I wrote, strictly for personal use. Currently I store the quantities for recipes as varchars. Example 1/3 cup is stored as 1/3 in a quantity varchar field and cup is stored in a measurement varchar field. The program currently allows me to select recipes and spit out a shopping list.

Now, the obvious problem is that if I need 1 onion for one recipe and 1/2 onion for another recipe, I end up with two lines on my ingredient shopping list. I am interested in finding a way to store ingredient quantities in such a way that I can add them when I go to make my shopping list.

Simplified version of my current RecipeIngredientTable

```
RecipeID Links to Recipe table
IngredientID Links to Ingredient table
qty - varchar - for 1/3, 1, .33, etc
measurement - varchar - for Cups, grams, ounces, etc (I am toying with splitting this into its own table as well, but that's for later)
```

I have looked at converting fractions to decimals (first option I thought of) but ran into a roadblock right away. Let's say that three different recipes each require 1/3 cup of milk. Now, when you add this it becomes one cup. But if I convert each of the 1/3 cups to decimal (.33) then add that together 3 times, I and end up with .99, or 99/100.

How would I handle converting this back to a fraction (in this case a whole number)? I am not sure whether this should be done sql server side or in my C# code.

I've also toyed with the idea of a lookup table with the more common fraction to decimal translations (1.4 = 0.25, 11/16 = 0.6875, 1/8 = 0.125, etc), and find a way to use the C# code to convert the decimal back to fraction for each individual ingredient, then jumping through hoops in code to start adding fractions together.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

As a side note, I realize that when I implement the new quantity storage in the database I will have to convert the existing recipes. I'll deal with that later.

Comment: I would store fractions as separate numerator and denominator columns. You can always convert them to decimals, and won't have to worry about the conversion back to fractions. Add fractions using fraction arithmetic. 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 3/3 = 1

Comment: fraction arithmetic may be challenging in pure sql. The 99/100 problem doesn't make sense to me. So what? If you only need 1/2 an onion don't you need to buy 1 full onion?  Just always round up, and use more precision

Comment: If you parse the fraction varchar (reasonably easy to do given the slash) and convert both parts to a double, you won't get 0.33 for 1/3, you will get whatever the double equivalent is of 0.3-repeating (remember fractional doubles aren't exact anyway). If you multiply that by 3.0, you will get within a very small epsilon of 1.0. With doubles, you should never check for equality anyway, you should check `abs(expected-actual) < epsilon`. So it _should just work_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am going to use Dan's and Garr's responses.

From Dan I am going to modify his suggestion and continue to store my fraction like I have been, but add a column to convert it to decimal.

As for Garr's response, this is KISS in its simplicity. I was way overthinking the problem. I like the idea of rounding up to the nearest whole number. It will allow me to add the decimals from the database and figure out basically how much I need of an item.

Thank you to both. I just wish there was a way to accept a comment as an answer.